# Did Yuno torture Yukiteru's mother in the first world?

Tags: mirai-nikki

After meeting Yukki's mom, Yuno is glad that she didn't have to use her "tools" to convince her. But at the end we know that this was the second time she went through her life, which means that she already passed by her first meeting with Yukki's mom. Yet she didn't expect to be accepted and therefore brought "tools" along with her....

Does that mean that in the first world she actually forced Yukiteru's mother to accept her in some way?

Comment: We don't know the details of what happend in the first world, just the general lines. Therefore, we can't say for sure how the meet between Yuno and Yuki's mother went for sure. IIRC there is no detail about this on the manga and the anime. If no one answers the question, I will post it tonight.